# Old version of Ruby overriding updated version

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

Ruby noob here. I installed Ruby 1.9.3 but it still defaults to my pre-installed system version (1.8). For example:

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

I used rbenv to try to set the global version to 1.9.3

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p448
```

But still, I have this issue and when I check the version, I get 1.8:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Comment: How did you install Ruby 1.9.3 ?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by adding the following to .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Also, this line is needed too (though it was already there):

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

For info on modifying bash_profile, see:

http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac

Answer (score 0):

Use rehash command for rbenv after setting a version.

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash

Answer (score 0):

Command gem use System gem command, default is superuser. I unused rbenv, but get rbenv path add to environment variables PATH at first, I think is work